# Multiple textures for one Mesh object

Tags: libgdx, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

In my game a player flys through space and has to avoid asteroids. Asteroids are just simple polygons which I draw using a Mesh class. For all the polygons I use just one Mesh class object and it works fine. To add a little variety to their looks I would like to use say 4 textures.

My question is, do I have to create different Mesh object for each texture or maybe there is a way to use just one Mesh class object? I read that it is best to use as little Mesh objects as possible to improve performance and since it is an Android game I certainly could use performance boost.

Inside draw method to bind one texture to a mesh I use this code:

```
mShaderProgram.begin();
mShaderProgram.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", mCamera.getCamera().combined);       
Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
mTexture.bind();
mMesh.render(mShaderProgram, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);        
mShaderProgram.end();
```

Comment: You can use as many textures as you like for one mesh.

Comment: @Xoppa: Thanks, can you give me a hint or two how to do it?

Comment: There's no difference between using one or more textures. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Xoppa: Sorry, I thought it was obvious that I am asking how to use eg. 4 different textures for 4 different polygons in the same mesh.

Comment: Without seeing any code, my guess is that you're better off using one mesh per texture. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Xoppa: I added the code I use to bind one texture to a mesh. And, well I usually write code after I know how to do it...

Comment: Apparently you aren't setting the texture unit and uniform (which you really should do, regardless the amount of textures), which suggests that you're using a basic shader (one sampler2d and only position and uv vertex attributes). Like said you're probably better off using one mesh per texture. If you really want to combine draw calls like this (I'd advise you to profile before these kind of (premature?) optimizations), then the easiest is probably to pack the four textures into one big texture and modify the UV coords to fit the correct texture region.